# Writing Math equations in MSE.

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax, soft-question, advice

How do I write the mathematical equations in a question, here on stack exchange?

When I try to write a question which involves equations, I get stuck as I don't know how to input those equations...

Anyone please tell me!

Comment: If you basic LaTeX/amsmath, it is usually the same code (equations numbering is not automatic: you have to use `\tag{some number/symbol}`).

Comment: If you want to know how a particular equation is formatted (i.e. to help you learn), you can press "improve this question/answer" to see how it was written, or you can right-click on a particular formatted block (you should see a pop-up menu) and press *Show Math As* $\to$ *TeX Commands* to see the code used. Put this code between `$` signs for inline maths (e.g. $a + b^2 = 10$) or `$$` signs for equations that take their own line, e.g. $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x = \sqrt{\pi}.$$

Comment: Yes that's good!

Answer (score 2):

For those with little experience in LaTeX, the best on-site source to consult is [mathjax basic tutorial and quck reference.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?r=SearchResults&s=10%7C36.2014)  This site uses MathJax software and MathJax relies a lot on LaTeX commands (not all), surrounded by dollar-signs.  The tutorial will help you get up to speed in no time.

When I started here, I became very familiar with MathJax by studying the tutorial, and suggesting edits to posts, using what I learned.  Until a user has earned 2000 in rep, any successful edit will earn you 2 reputation points.  It's a great way to practice what you're learning.

Also, whenever you see something formatted and want to know how to do that, you can "right-click" on the formatted expression/equation, choose "show math as..." and then choose "TeX", and you'll be able to see and or copy the formatting.

Comment: To see the source you can also click on "edit". I find this more useful, as you get to see the bigger picture (including how links are formatted, etc.).

Comment: True, @user1729, provided the equation of interest is in a question or answer.  But sometimes knowing to right click is useful across questions, answers, AND COMMENTS.